# CentOS equivalent of dpkg -s

Tags: ubuntu, package, centos, rpm, dpkg

I'm adapting a prepare script for CentOS that was previously written for Ubuntu.

In the Ubuntu script, the command `dpkg -s {some program}` is called frequently. For example, one such command is `dpkg -s snmpd` to check if the SNMP Daemon is installed.

What is the equivalent in CentOS? I know that RPM is the package manager. The command `rpm -q` is similar, but it looks for packages and not programs.

For example, running `rpm -q snmpd` returns:

```
package snmpd is not installed
```

My question is, what is the CentOS equivalent of the Ubuntu command `dpkg -s` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dpkg -s` does take a package name, not a file or program, as an argument.  (In many cases, a program will have the same name as the package that provides it.)

For example, on my Ubuntu system, `dpkg -s gcc` prints:

```
Package: gcc
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Installed-Size: 64
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Source: gcc-defaults (1.98ubuntu3)
Version: 4:4.5.2-1ubuntu3
Provides: c-compiler
Depends: cpp (>= 4:4.5.2-1ubuntu3), gcc-4.5 (>= 4.5.2-1~)
Recommends: libc6-dev | libc-dev
Suggests: gcc-multilib, make, manpages-dev, autoconf, automake1.9, libtool, flex, bison, gdb, gcc-doc
Conflicts: gcc-doc (<< 1:2.95.3)
Description: The GNU C compiler
 This is the GNU C compiler, a fairly portable optimizing compiler for C.
  .
   This is a dependency package providing the default GNU C compiler.
   Original-Maintainer: Debian GCC Maintainers <debian-gcc@lists.debian.org>
```

On a CentOS system, `rpm -q gcc` prints:

```
gcc-4.1.2-50.el5
```

It doesn't print as much information, but if all you're doing is checking whether a package is installed, it should be ok.  If you need more information or other options, `man rpm`; other queries are available.

If `rpm -q snmpd` prints `package snmpd is not installed`, that's probably just the information you need.

Both `dpkg -s` and `rpm -q` set the exit status accordingly, reporting failure if the package isn't installed.